# Group Theory(Disjoint Cycles)

Tags: group-theory

I need a simple definition of Disjoint cycles in Symmetric Groups.I already understand what cycles and Transpositions are. I need a simple definition and if possible,give a clear example.Thanks in advance Mathematician

Answer (score 2):

Disjoint cycles have no cycle elements in common.  For example $(1, 2, 3)$ and $(4,5,6,7)$ are disjoint cycles.

By contrast, $(1,2,3)$ and $(3,4,5,6)$ are not disjoint because they have the $3$ in common.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a permutation of a set that has the property that, for example, elements of  two disjoint subsets are permuted  within each subset as cycles in each subset.

$S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\};\ A=\{1,4,9\};\ B={2,3,5,6,7,8}$

The permutation  of $S$ sending 1 to 4, 4 to 9, 9 to 1, 2 to 3, 3 to 5, 5 to 6,  6 to 7, 7 to 8 and 8 to 2$ is not a cycle, but consists of two disjoint cycles of length 3 and 6 respectively. (You can think of them going around parallelly in two different circles). The concept is not limited to just two cycles. Also any fixed point of the permutation is regarded as a cycle of length 1.